# Seeking a simulation framework in Javascript

Tags: javascript, frameworks, open-source, simulation

I need a simulation framework in Javascript, which is open source. With the simulation framework can create a probability distribution.

Comment: Even if this question were translated, it'd require more information. In this state, a "What have you tried" link is bound to be posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this library:

http://www.jstat.org/

Things like NormalDistribution and so on.

Comment: Is this library "jstat" an Open Source js-library?

Comment: Well you can download the development code, uncompressed. Makes it easy to edit it.